# How to write contents of one file to another file?

Tags: c#, .net

I need to write contents of a file to another file using File.OpenRead and File.OpenWrite methods. I am unable to figure out how to do it.

How can i modify the following code to work for me.

```
using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead("C:\\file1.txt"))
using (FileStream writeStream = File.OpenWrite("D:\\file2.txt"))
{
       BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream);
       BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(writeStream);
       writer.Write(reader.ReadBytes(stream.Length));
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you posted? What error you get?

Comment: I m confused about whther i should be reading all bytes in one go or not? what are the implications and besides stream.length is long while reader.ReadBytes expects int.

Comment: your question is key - should you be reading all bytes in one go or not?  The implication is how much memory you want your process to be using when this chunk of code is called (based on file size, of course).  Reading it all in one go could cost a lot of memory.  Other answers show how to chunk it up in 1K or 4K bites.  If you chunk it, note that it could result in a performance penalty.  Those are your trade-offs.  Analyze your situation and choose which fits your requirements best.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
    using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead("C:\\file1.txt"))
    using (FileStream writeStream = File.OpenWrite("D:\\file2.txt"))
    {
        BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream);
        BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(writeStream);

        // create a buffer to hold the bytes 
        byte[] buffer = new Byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;

        // while the read method returns bytes
        // keep writing them to the output stream
        while ((bytesRead =
                stream.Read(buffer, 0, 1024)) > 0)
        {
            writeStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    }
```

Just wonder why not to use this:

```
File.Copy("C:\\file1.txt", "D:\\file2.txt");
```

Comment: Are the BinaryReader and BinaryWriter statements necesarry?

Comment: Sure you can replace them with "var"

Comment: Could you tell me the use of those two statements?  In other words, what would happen without these two statements?

Comment: The File.Copy is so simple! Thank you!

Comment: I could see the scenario where you would like to get FileStreams open successfully on a set of files before overwriting them.  That way you don't have 2 of your 5 files overwritten if you were to use File.Copy. To do that you would need FileStream's open on all the files first, then overwrite them using the filestreams you already opened in conjunction with Binary writer and reader

Answer (score 6):

You should be using `File.Copy` unless you want to append to the second file.

If you want to append you can still use the File class.

```
string content = File.ReadAllText("C:\\file1.txt");
File.AppendAllText("D:\\file2.txt",content);
```

This works for file with small size as entire file in loaded into the memory.

Comment: Simple and good for small files. Obviously you wouldn't want to use this for large files, as you'd be loading the entire file content into memory.

Answer (score 3):

Try something along these lines:

```
using (FileStream input = File.OpenRead(pathToInputFile),
    output = File.OpenWrite(pathToOutputFile))
{
    int read = -1;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    while (read != 0)
    {
        read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        output.Write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
}
```

Note that this is somewhat 'skeletal' and you should amend as required for your application of it.

Comment: Why do u say, i shoould change it as required by my application? Do u mean to say i need to decide the chunk size (which in your case is 4mb)? Should we really read bytes in chunks or can do it in one go?

Comment: @Sumee I imagine that the reading it all in one go, is dependent on your filesize, if you have a really massive file, perhaps reading all could be too large for your buffer? (I don't know what happens, other then I suspect you might not get all the text as you expect)

Comment: @Wes Price - sorry i meant 4k

Comment: @Summe: Yes, change the file paths and buffer length to what is required. Reading in increments could benefit you, as onaclov2000 mentions, if you have a large file then there are a couple of symptoms which may occur which this approach could help you mitigate.

Comment: @Eugene: I believe the offset would be used to specify an offset from the current position in either file, we, however, do not require any further offset as the location we are at in either file is dictated by how many bytes we last read or have written.

Comment: @MikeBlandford Oops, fixed, but you know you can edit stuff like that, right?

Answer (score 1):

Is it necessary to us FileStream? Because you can do this very easily with simple File Class like;

```
using System.IO;
string FileContent = File.ReadAllText(FilePathWhoseTextYouWantToCopy);
File.WriteAllText(FilePathToWhomYouWantToPasteTheText,FileContent);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using (var inputStream = File.OpenRead(@"C:\file1.txt"))
{
    using (var outputStream = File.OpenWrite(@"D:\file2.txt"))
    {
        int bufferLength = 128;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferLength];
        int bytesRead = 0;

        do
        {
            bytesRead = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
            outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        while (bytesRead != 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: will this append or write over?

Answer (score 0):

Use `FileStream` class, from `System.IO`.

```
[ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
public class FileStream : Stream
```

Comment: my code sample uses filestream. How should i modify this code to work?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that the reader is reading all the data? [This MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.readbytes.aspx) has an example that checks all the data is read:

```
    byte[] verifyArray = binReader.ReadBytes(arrayLength);
    if(verifyArray.Length != arrayLength)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error reading the data.");
        return;
    }
```

The other alternative is that you probably need to [`Flush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.flush.aspx) the output buffer:

```
writer.Flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not keen at using Read/Write function of File , you can better try using Copy functionality

```
Easiest will be : 

      File.Copy(source_file_name, destination_file_name, true)
```

true--> for overwriting existing file,without "true" it will create a new file.But if the file already exists it will throw exception without "true" argument.