# Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: FileBufferingReadStream

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, stream

I'm trying to upload files in azure.

So basically I'm trying to convert the file in a stream so I can create a file on server and write its data.

```
   public async Task UploadFileOnAzure( string path, string name, IFormFile file)
    {
        //create directory
        await _dlsService.CreateDir(path, name);
        //create file
        var f = file.FileName;
        var ext = Path.GetExtension(f);
        string filepath = $"{path}/{name.ToString()}/{f}";
        try
        {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var fileStram = file.OpenReadStream())
                {//sometimes it breakes right before this line, other times it doesn't write the file(excel)
                    fileStram.CopyTo(ms);
                    using (Stream str = await _dlsService.CreateFile(filepath)) //file is created as empty ofcourse
                    {
                        ms.CopyTo(str);
                        str.Close();
                        //this doesnt write on the file
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
        }


    }
```

**Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: FileBufferingReadStream.** I get this error quite often. Can't seem to understand why. 
I would like to just write on the created file. Pls help :)

Comment: A using statement will dispose and object (flush, close as well )outside the clause.  You will get an error if you try to do the close in code.

Comment: Exactly where are you receiving that error?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ sometimes i get the error on this line `var fileStram = file.OpenReadStream()` . Other times I don't get an error but nothing is written to the file. Is this a correct way of uploading a file? Or writing one?

Comment: @jdweng I already know that, but I'm inside the using statement. So I guess there was not suppossed to be any problem on this case... right?? Can you suggest me a way of how to the file in a stream and than use `copyTo` method to write on the created file? Or any way of uploading a file in azure. I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Has the file object already been disposed by the time you get here - file.OpenReadStream()? i.e. where you are calling this function, is there a using block there - I'm going only by the error message and its location.

Comment: @Rakesh No, the has not been disposed. As I said this sometimes happens, and sometimes not. Anyway, why in the cases that doen't raise an exception, it doesn't write to `str` object? Can you give me an example?

Comment: Does it EVER write any data - or is there an intermittent issue.
Temporarily remove the using blocks to see if that is the source or of if this is coming in from elsewhere.

Comment: No it never writes the data @Rakesh. That's the problem. Even in the cases that it doen;t raise the error.  Should I use memory stream? Should I just use stream? Any idea? or approach?

Comment: Remove the using statements and try.
We can go from there.

Comment: I tried that and it says `Cannot access a closed Stream.` @Rakesh

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200567/discussion-between-rakesh-and-pavel).

Comment: Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914445/how-to-write-contents-of-one-file-to-another-file) for a similar question on copying file data.

Comment: I found the problem guys. There was a call that I wouldn't await that would couse me this much trouble. Thanks you.